# Can a method of a subclass of an abstract super class return a super class of the super class return type?

Tags: java, interface, subclass, abstract, superclass

I have an abstract super class that implements an interface:

```
public abstract class FooMatrix implements Matrix {
    public Vector multiply(Vector vec) {
        // Code for Matrix * Vector
    }
}

public interface Matrix {
    public Vector multiply(Vector vec);
}
```

and then I have a subclass that extends the super class and implements a second interface that  represents a mathematical subclass of the mathematical class represented by the first interface:

```
public interface Vector {
    // Methods
}

public class FooVector extends FooMatrix implements Vector {
    @Override
    public Matrix multiply(Vector rightVec) {
        // Code for Vector * Vector
    }
}
```

So the subclass is returning a super class of the return type of the abstract super class. This isn't working, and I want to know how I can make it work.

In mathematics, vectors are a subclass of matrices. A matrix times a matrix yields another matrix, in general. If the second matrix is a vector, the result is a vector. If both matrices are vectors, the result is a matrix or a scalar for column vector times row vector or row vector times column vector, respectively. This assumes the dimensions are compatible.

I would like to represent this behaviour with Java classes in a way that respects mathematics and gives the most specific return types possible. In other words, I want `fooMatrix.multiply(Vector vec)` to return `Vector`, and not just `Matrix`, but I want `fooVector.multiply(Vector rightVec)` to return `Matrix` and not `Vector` (which would be incorrect.) I can deal with a scalar as a 1x1 `Matrix` with another `Vector` method `inner` that calls `multiply(Vector rightVec)` and then returns the single element of the 1x1 return `Matrix` as a scalar.

I have found questions regarding covariant return types, but nothing like this.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you'd be much, much better off not trying to make `Vector` a subclass of `Matrix`.

Comment: To change the return type itself, I think you should make it generic, with a bounded type parameter.

Comment: I think that my best bet is making Vector implement Matrix and creating an additional interface Covector that implements Matrix as well. Then I can specify Matrix*Matrix = Matrix, Matrix*Vector = Vector, Covector*Matrix = Covector, Covector*Vector = Number, and Vector*Covector = Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Matrix` and `Vector` are in two different hierarchies. You cant use `Matrix` in place of `Vector` as a return type.
If you are not sure of the return type whether its going to be of type `Matrix` or `Vector`, you can new interface which is extended by `Matrix` and `Vector` and use it as return type.
Somewhat like

```
public interface MatrixOrVector {
    // This can be used as return type
}
```

change `Matrix` to

```
public interface Matrix extends MatrixOrVector{
   // Methods...
}
```

same with Vector

```
public interface Vector extends MatrixOrVector{
    // Methods ....
}
```

If you use `MatrixOrVector` as return type, you can return object which is of type `Matrix` or `Vector`.

Also just FYI `FooMatrix` is not a abstract class because you are missing `abstract` there. read more about abstract http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: Thanks for catching my omission of 'abstract', Ajinkya. I can't blame it on my ignorance, only lack of sleep.